# Copy specific Column from multiple csv file and write it to new csv file. Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, shell-script, csv, columns

I have multiple CSV files from these I want to extract 3rd column and write it new file, in the same manner, the file is sequenced in a folder. Append should be in such a manner that all the columns come side by side and not one below another.
I used multiple commands

```
paste -d "," *csv >> Main.csv
```

Resulted in improper sequences of the data appending. Files sequencing was wrong. (wasn't able to understand how to append-only specific columns, entire file was appended but were side by side)

```
cut -d ',' -f1-2 *.csv t.csv
```

Resulted in appending data one below another instead of side by side. (and appended two columns which I can change to append one column).

```
cut -d ',' -f1-2 File1.csv | paste File2.csv - > Main.csv
```

This method worked for 2 files but again how to extend it to reading multiple files.

```
Eg:-
File_1.csv
a,32,37
b,26,34 
c,56,65

File_2.csv
a,92,60
b,48,63 
c,52,23

File_3.csv
a,2,37
b,45,53 
c,56,63
.
.
.
.


Output_File.csv
a,37,60,37 . . . .
b,34,63,53 . . . .
c,65,23,63 . . . .
```

Comment: Can you provide input and output examples of what you want?

Comment: Are you just looking for `paste <(cut -d',' -f2 *csv)`?

Comment: paste <(cut -d',' -f2 *csv) this works well but columns are appended one below another. I want them to be listed side by side.

Comment: The data that you show does not use commas as delimiters but instead seems to use a varying number of space characters. Is that correct? If so, why are you consistently trying to use `cut` with `,` as delimiter?

Comment: I am sorry for being a vague example. In actual columns are separated by commas as delimiter. I just wanted to give an idea how these file would look like. I will make an edit. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes that

1. The CSV data is "simple", meaning its fields do not contain embedded commas or newlines.
2. All files have the same number of rows.
3. The current directory contains at least one CSV file.

Let us start by getting a list of the files:

```bsh
rm -f out.csv
filelist=( *.csv )
```

This creates an array called `filelist` containing the names of all files in the current directory that match the pattern `*.csv`.  I started by removing `out.csv` as we will use that name for the result file and we don't want to include that in the processing if it exists.

Then we extract the first column from the first of these files.  We save the column to a new file called `out.csv`.

```bsh
cut -d , -f 1 -- "${filelist[0]}" >out.csv
```

We then loop over the files, pulling out the 3rd column of each file and adding it to the existing `out.csv` file by means of `cut`, `paste`, and an intermediate file called `out.tmp`.

```bsh
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
    cut -d , -f 3 -- "$file" | paste -d , out.csv - >out.tmp &&
    mv out.tmp out.csv
done
```

The whole thing, but rewritten for `/bin/sh` (which has no arrays):

```bsh
rm -f out.csv
set -- *.csv

cut -d , -f 1 -- "$1" >out.csv

for file do
    cut -d , -f 3 -- "$file" | paste -d , out.csv - >out.tmp &&
    mv out.tmp out.csv
done
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kusalananda. This is a much cleaner way, might be helpful while I am doing multiple iterations through the same folders, as my answer doesn't take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Code i am finding it easy to use is .

```
  paste -d"," *csv>>OG.csv
  cut --complement -d',' -f3,4,5,7,8,10,.. OG.csv>>Data.csv
```

if there are any alternate ways please let time know.

Comment: If you want to pull out only the third column from each file, then this is not it. It's also unclear why you are using `>>`, or whether your `OG.csv` and `Data.csv` files exists from the start (and whether these also should be included in the `*csv` globbing).

Comment: If I pull only third column then I miss will the columns with a,b, and c as identifiers that I need. And since the first column is the same for all I went through by first writing data to file and then deleting it later by cut compliment. Regarding >> I could have used > instead, since files are created for first time itself so these didn't made any changes to desired file. but yes had it been in loop I might have had errors in the data appending. Additionally since you mentioned if you can tell me how to specifically remove file from *csv globbing it would be helpful later.